# Python/Flask: Application is running after closing

Tags: python, eclipse, web-applications, flask, pydev

I'm working on a simple Flask web application. I use Eclipse/Pydev. When I'm working on the app, I have to restart this app very often because of code changes. And that's the problem. When I run the app, I can see the frame on my localhost, which is good. But when I want to close this app, just click on the red square which should stop applications in Eclipse, sometimes (often), the old version of application keeps running so I can't test the new version. In this case the only thing which helps is to force close every process in Windows Task Manager.

Will you give me any advice how to manage this problem? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: This maybe helps: Many times, I have to run the app twice. Otherwise I can't connect.

Comment: Are you setting `app.debug=True` in your application? See [flask debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode) this will automatically reload the application based on your code changes. Therefore, you only need to run the application _once_. You should also not run it in "debug mode" (whatever is the equivalent in Eclipse). Instead, just run it as a normal application. Due to any interruption if you are running in debug mode, the thread is not stopped, only blocked. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, I have debug mode set.  It is working better without debug mode I think but there are issues sometimes too.

Comment: @Milano I'm facing the same issue. I'm using spyder IDE to run the application and chrome to see the output. Did u find any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same problem and solved it. I think it may help.

When we run a flask based site locally it is assigned to a TCP port: 5000 and the Default IP: 127.0.0.1:5000

Sometimes TCP connection remains even after closing the program or terminating the code. So, The idea is kill the TCP connection. You can do it from command-prompt(**cmd**)

Two Steps to Follow: 
*1.* See the Process ID(**PID**) for the running TCP connection. 
Go to cmd and type:

```
netstat -ano
```

[image]

2. Kill The Process By PID. Command for this: *taskkill /f /im [PID]*. Example is showed bellow.

   taskkill /f /im 7332

Comment: This worked for me. I was getting: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. I eventually figured out this was coming from the ghost Flask server of an earlier IDE shutdown, not the server I had just started. Using Flask under the JetBrains PyCharm IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very similar thing happen to me. I was using CherryPy rather than Flask, but my solution might still work for you. Oftentimes browsers save webpages locally so that they don't have to re-download them every time the website is visited. This is called caching, and although it's very useful for the average web user, it can be a real pain to app developers. If you're frequently generating new versions of the application, it's possible that your browser is displaying an old version of the app that it has cached instead of the most up to date version. I recommend clearing that cache every time you restart your application, or disabling the cache altogether.

Comment: I tried to clear the cache but my problem keep being. So I tried to start Internet Explorer (I use Chrome) and type  http://127.0.0.1:5000/ and I saw the application running but I've stopped it in Eclipse before.. Probably it won't be the cache issue...

Answer (score 1):

This actually shouldn't happen with the latest versions of PyDev (i.e.: since PyDev 3.4.1: http://pydev.org/history_pydev.html, PyDev should kill all the subprocesses of the main process).

So, can you check which PyDev version are you using?

If you're in the latest version of PyDev, you can use Ctrl+Shift+F9 to terminate/relaunch by default.

But as you're dealing with flask, you should be able to use it to reload automatically on code-changes without doing anything by setting use_reloader=True.

I.e.: I haven't actually tested, but its documentation says that you can set the reload flag for that run(use_reloader=True) -- and PyDev should even be able to debug it (I'll take a better look and improve the PyDev docs on that area later on).