# Can I bring down a Flask server after deleting the original code?

Tags: python, flask

I made a Flask app and ran it. I then deleted the Flask app's module without stopping the server and closed the command prompt by mistake. However, the server is still running. What should I do?

Comment: What do you want to happen? If you want to shut down the server, you can find the Python process running it in your OS's task manager and kill it.

Comment: you can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349335/python-flask-application-is-running-after-closing